# Windows: How to make command line prompt open at a different path?

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to change the properties of Windows that when I open a command line prompt window, it will be opened at another path that the current one. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: What programing language are you using?

Comment: Just create a link to cmd.exe and set its working directory to the one you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a shortcut to cmd.exe. Then do this :

Right click on **Command Prompt > Properties > Shortcut**. There you'll see a line which says **Target:** ". There just specify in which folder you want the cmd to start in.

[Where you need to be, after accessing Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q227E.png)

If you add `/k cd "\path\to\folder"` to the Target field (after `cmd.exe`), the resultant Command Prompt window will execute the `cd` command and then leave you with a prompt to do with as you please. If you need to change to a different drive, you'll need `cd /d` rather than just `cd`. If you need to change to a network drive, use `pushd` instead - it automatically mounts the target UNC path as a drive and changes to it.